# What's going on with my routes? Rails 4

Tags: rspec, routes, rails-routing

So as far as I know my routing file - for a brand new project to create a `site.com/users/create` I do:

```
StartPoint::Application.routes.draw do
  resource :users
end
```

But upon running my tests I get:

```
INFO - Running: spec/routing
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/adam/Documents/Rails-StartPoint/StartPoint/spec/routing (LoadError)
```

Which I guess that just means its a routing error?

Comment: That's a RSpec error. Could be a problem with your routing spec, could be a problem with your RSpec installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your spec directory. It should have a routing sub-directory for routing specs. If not, just create an empty one. Apparently, RSpec does not create any sub-directories under spec when running `rails g rspec:install` ,but expects it to be there